# How to use one variable/property instead assigning same property three times?

Tags: swift, properties

Let's assume that **myVar** has *same* functionality in every implementation of **view**. I am trying to figure out how to declare/expose some kind of *set-only* property instead of assigning them n-times (with every new *view* created), but nothing comes to my head. How could I refactor into one line & one time assignment?

```
var myVar: (()-> Void)?

private func callBack() {
    someClass.view1.myVar = self.myVar
    someClass.view2.myVar = self.myVar
    someClass.view3.myVar = self.myVar
}

// MARK: - someClass pseudocode

someClass: class {
    let view1: CustomView: = CustomView
    let view2: CustomView: = CustomView
    let view3: CustomView: = CustomView
}

// MARK: - customView pseudocode

class CustomView: UIView {
    var myVar: (()-> Void)?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this, but having all `CustomViews` in an array is good idea and could be implemented here as well

```
var a: (() -> Void)?

class CustomView: UIView {
    var myVar: (() -> Void)?
}

class SomeClass {
    let view1 = CustomView()
    let view2 = CustomView()
    let view3 = CustomView()
    var myVar: (() -> Void)? {
        set {
            self.view2.myVar = newValue
            self.view1.myVar = newValue
            self.view3.myVar = newValue
        }

        get {
            return self.myVar
        }
    }
}

let b = SomeClass()
b.myVar = ({print(3)})
b.view1.myVar!()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

`[someClass.view1, someClass.view2, someClass.view3].forEach { $0.myVar = self.myVar }`

Comment: That's smart, but this does basically the same, just the syntax of it is very **Swifty**.

It still assigns myVar three times.

Comment: I tried to do this but **$0** is immutable, as I tried to assign something like that `{$0.myVar = { self.myVar?() } }`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tend to deal with these issues:

```
class OtherClass {
    var text: String?
    init(text: String?) {
        self.text = text;
    }
}
class TestClass {
    var thing1: OtherClass?
    var thing2: OtherClass?
    var thing3: OtherClass?


    var allTheThings: [OtherClass?] { return [thing1, thing2, thing3]}

    var ownText: String? {
        didSet {
            allTheThings.forEach { $0?.text = ownText }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on how much you expect things to change you could make the array property a constant you set in your init rather than a computed property.

If you want to get fancy you could also do something like this for setting:

```
    private var allTheThings: [OtherClass?] {
        get {
            return [thing1, thing2, thing3]
        }
        set {
            guard newValue.count == 3 else {
                //probably should put an assertion in here
                return
            }
            thing1 = newValue[0]
            thing2 = newValue[1]
            thing3 = newValue[2]
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.allTheThings = Array(repeating: OtherClass(text: "Test"), count: 3)
    }
```